# Dataprep change str yyyymmdd date to datetime column

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataprep

I have a column with dates (in a string format) in Dataprep: yyyymmdd. I would like it to become a datetime object. Which function/transformation should I apply to achieve this result automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you actually don't need to apply a transformation at all—you can just change column type to Date/Time and select the appropriate format options.

**Note:** This is one of the least intuitive parts of Dataprep as you have to select an *incorrect* format (in this case `yy-mm-dd`) before you can drill-down to the *correct* format (`yyyymmdd`).

Here's a screenshot of the Date / Time type window to illustrate this:
[image: Google Cloud Dataprep Date/Time type picker dialog showing the yy-mm-dd type and yyyymmdd subtype selected]

While it's unintuitive, this will correctly treat the column as a date in future operations, including assigning the correct type in export operations (e.g. BigQuery).

Through the UI, this will generate the following Wrangle Script:

```
settype col: YourDateCol customType: 'Datetime','yy-mm-dd','yyyymmdd' type: custom
```

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Settype-Transform_57344649), this should also work (and is more succinct):

```
settype col: YourDateCol type: 'Datetime','yy-mm-dd','yyyymmdd'
```

---

Note that if you absolutely needed to do this in a function context, you could extract the date parts using [`SUBSTRING`](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/SUBSTRING-Function_57344730)/[`LEFT`](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/LEFT-Function_57344731)/[`RIGHT`](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/RIGHT-Function_57344732) and pass them to the [`DATE`](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/DATE-Function_57344705) or [`DATETIME`](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/DATETIME-Function_102563869) function to construct a datetime object.  As you've probably already found, [`DATEFORMAT`](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/DATEFORMAT-Function_57344708) will return NULL if the source column isn't already of type `Datetime`.

(From a performance standpoint though, it would probably be far more efficient for a large dataset to either just change the the or create a new column with the correct type versus having to perform those extra operations on so many rows.)

Comment: Thank you for that. Indeed unintuitive as I had seen that list but couldn't find my option. Where can we access the initial Wrangle script of the library items? The reason I am asking is because I would like for certain datasets to have always the same Wrangle script, and not change it each time when I put it into a flow (eg. first row = header, remove rows where the dates are mismatches and apply the above operation)

Comment: @JohnAndrews This may be better served as a separate SO question so I can post images, but the basics are that you can download a recipe's script by clicking the "..." (More) icon on the top-right of the recipe pane, then selecting "Download Recipe as wrangle".

You can also copy the wrangle script for any single item by clicking the "..." (More) icon that appears on hover and selecting "Copy to clipboard".  This can then be applied to any other recipe by clicking "New Step" and pasting from your clipboard (which will re-create the step in the interface).

Comment: @JohnAndrews I also have a flow called `!TEMPLATES` where I store common base recipes like you described.  When I need them, I click the "..." next to them and select "Make a copy > Without Inputs" to clone it, and then on the copy click the same "..." menu and select "Move..." which brings up a dialog allowing you to move the recipe to another flow or create a new flow. While it isn't as painless as it should be, I find this faster than having to create the recipes step by step (pasting the lines from the downloaded wrangle script).